# Is there a way to recover Gmail messages that were deleted maliciously from an account?

Tags: gmail

A friend of mine fell victim to a mailbox hijacker the other day, and Gmail helped her recover the inbox (via whatever method they do so, I was not present for that). I showed her how to recover her contacts (that has a handy recovery menu option) but she's missing data for about a week of email. It's not "hidden" in a filter, it's not "in the deleted bin".

Is there any way to get all of that emails back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once messages have been deleted by clicking `Delete Forever` it is not possible to retrieve the messages via the the Gmail interface.

In cases where an account has been compromised, you can file a report to Google and request that they investigate whether recovery is possible.

[Recovering deleted Gmail messages for compromised accounts](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/bin/request.py?&ctx=bugflow_receive31&contact_type=bugs)

Source: [Google Help article](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78353)

Comment: Oh wow, I missed that somehow (not very hard to do) so let me make sure she's aware of that. Thanks!